# Replace a php variable when submitting html form

Tags: php, forms

I'd like to know how I can rewrite a php variable when submit the form. Is it possible?
For example, I've got a page (page-with-variable-i-want-to-replace.php) where I store a variable:

```
<?php
$myVars = array("Variable-1" => "Variable-2");
?>
```

And I got an HTML-form:

```
<form type="POST" action="page-with-variable-i-want-to-replace.php">
  <label>Insert new Variable:
      <input name="myVars" type="text" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How can I replace **Variable-2** by submitting the html-form?

Comment: You basically want to create an array with the input's value right? use `$_POST` that's pretty basic, you may want to see a tutorial or even better read directly from the PHP documentation.

Comment: You should really [start by reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) SO is not a tutorial site I am afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first take the new variable after submitting the form using `$_POST['myvars']` in your  `page-with-variable-i-want-to-replace.php` and the loop through the array `$myvars` and change the content

```
foreach($myvar as $key => $value)
{
  $myvar[$key]['Variable-1'] = $_POST['myvars');
}
```

I guess it will work fine and comment if I understood teh question wrongly